# Why can I see the data from a second sde database connection in my database?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I have an sde 9.3 database which when opened in arccatalog shows the data from another sde database. Under settings > Source this is confirmed. Why and how can this happen? The only thing the 2 databases have in common is that the owner is the same.

Comment: what is the database being used? Are the two sde geodatabases located on the same server or different servers. Such problems happens usually with oracle when you confuse different TNS names.

Comment: Both sde databases are on the same MSSQL Server.